# An error ocurred while starting the kernel 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

I can run this code and everything is OK:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
def plot_history(net_history):
history = net_history.history
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
losses = history['loss']
val_losses = history['val_loss']
accuracies = history['acc']
val_accuracies = history['val_acc']

plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.plot(losses)
plt.plot(val_losses)
plt.legend(['loss', 'val_loss'])

plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.plot(accuracies)
plt.plot(val_accuracies)
plt.legend(['acc', 'val_acc'])

# Load data
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

# Data attributes
X_train = train_images.reshape(60000, 784)
X_test = test_images.reshape(10000, 784)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

from keras.utils import np_utils
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(test_labels)

#==================================================
# Creating our model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy

myModel = Sequential()
myModel.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
myModel.add(Dropout(20))
myModel.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
myModel.add(Dropout(20))
myModel.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

myModel.summary()
myModel.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001), loss=categorical_crossentropy, 
metrics=['accuracy'])

#==================================================
# Train our model
network_history = myModel.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, 
validation_split=0.2)
plot_history(network_history)
```

but when  I can't run code_2:

```
#code_2
from keras.datasets import mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

# Data attributes    
X_train = train_images.reshape(60000, 28 , 28 ,1)
X_test = test_images.reshape(10000, 28, 28, 1)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255
from keras.utils import np_utils
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(test_labels)
# Creating our model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Input, Flatten, Dense
import keras
myInput = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(myInput)
pool1= MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2)(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(pool1)
pool2= MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2)(conv2)

flat = Flatten()(pool2)

out_layer = Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')(flat)

myModel = Model(myInput, out_layer)

myModel.summary()
myModel.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

#==================================================
# Train our model
network_history = myModel.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=2, 
validation_split=0.2)
```

**ERORR**

> An error ocurred while starting the kernel
>   2018 15:26:08.943071: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties: 
>   name: GeForce GT 740M major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0325
>   pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
>   totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.91GiB
>   2018 15:26:08.943124: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
>   2018 15:26:09.399518: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>   2018 15:26:09.399535: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:917] 0 
>   2018 15:26:09.399540: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:930] 0: N 
>   2018 15:26:09.399664: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1700 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 740M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)

**Dependencies**

IPython >=4.0    :  6.2.1 (OK)

cython >=0.21    :  0.27.3 (OK)

jedi >=0.9.0     :  0.11.1 (OK)

nbconvert >=4.0  :  5.3.1 (OK)

numpy >=1.7      :  1.14.2 (OK)

pandas >=0.13.1  :  0.22.0 (OK)

pycodestyle >=2.3:  2.3.1 (OK)

pyflakes >=0.6.0 :  1.6.0 (OK)

pygments >=2.0   :  2.2.0 (OK)

pylint >=0.25    :  1.8.2 (OK)

qtconsole >=4.2.0:  4.3.1 (OK)

rope >=0.9.4     :  0.10.7 (OK)

sphinx >=0.6.6   :  1.6.6 (OK)

sympy >=0.7.3    :  1.1.1 (OK)